# Set height and width of Google Map

Tags: angular-google-maps

I'm trying to use @angular/google-maps and I have a map showing at 500px X 500px and I am trying to set a custom height and width but it seems that the map-container class overrides the style of the  tag??

I can not use .scss because I need the height and width to react to variables in the .ts

This seems like it should be a no-brainer but I've working on it for hours now!

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I started using @bespunky/angular-google-maps easier that @angular/google-maps and fixes most of the problems with @agm/core

It's the best library out there currently for using Google maps in angular.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to define it inside your HTML

```
`<google-map
 #myGoogleMap
 id="map"
 [zoom]="zoom"
 [height]="600"
 [width]="550"
>
</google-map>`
```